# Case Team Members in Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce-template

I created a Visualforce email template on case, and I want to include the list of Case Team Members in the email.  How would I do that?  This is what I have so far...I put the ContactID on there just to see if I could access at least something from the Case Team.  It seems like a I can, but I don't know how to get a list of their names.  I'm very new to this so any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
> <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Auction ECR Request Scheduled"
> recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
>     <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    <html>
    <body>
            <table align="center">

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <p>The request you submitted Case# {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} on 
                              <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                 <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Requested_Date__c}"/> 
                              </apex:outputText>
                              has been scheduled by AiM. The CR writers will be on site 
                              <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                 <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Date_Scheduled__c}"/> 
                              </apex:outputText>.
                           </p>
                      </td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <p>
                   Contact ID: {!relatedTo.TeamMembers}
                   </p>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>

                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <p>Vendor Notes: 
                              {!relatedTo.Vendor_Notes__c}
                           </p>
                      </td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>

                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <p>Please contact us if you have any questions or if you need additional assistance.</p>
                      </td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>
                   <tr><td></td></tr>

                   <tr>
                      <td>
                          <p>Thank You,</p>
                      </td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr><td></td></tr>

                   <tr> 
                      <td>
                         <p>Support Team</p>
                      </td>   
                   </tr>

            </table>
        </body>             
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo...I finally figured this out using information provided on the page below.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample

Here's the code that worked as I needed it to...

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Auction ECR Request Scheduled" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
        <body>
                <table align="center">
                      <tr><td>Greetings - </td></tr>

                      <tr><td></td></tr>
                      <tr><td></td></tr>
                      <tr><td></td></tr>     

                      <tr>
                          <td>
                               <p>The request you submitted Case# {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} on&nbsp;
                                 <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                     <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Requested_Date__c}"/> 
                                  </apex:outputText>
                                  has been scheduled by AiM. The CR writers will be on site&nbsp;
                                  <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                     <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.Date_Scheduled__c}"/> 
                                  </apex:outputText>.
                               </p>
                           </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>CR Writers: </td>
                     </tr>
                     <apex:repeat var="ct" value="{!relatedTo.TeamMembers}">
                         <tr>
                          <td>{!ct.Member.Name}</td>
                         </tr>
                     </apex:repeat>

                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <br></br>

                       <tr>
                          <td>Vendor Notes: </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td>{!relatedTo.Vendor_Notes__c}</td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <br></br>

                       <tr>
                          <td>
                              <p>Please contact us if you have any questions or if you need additional assistance.</p>
                          </td>
                       </tr>

                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>
                       <tr><td></td></tr>

                       <tr>
                          <td>
                              <p>Thank You,</p>
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                </table>
            </body>             
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```